# cp didn't copy all files few files were missing

Tags: cp

How is it possible that cp didn't copy all files from a huge directory?

I did cp on a large directory with 5000 files. I checked contents with diff and it was not matching! How is this possible?

I ran `cp -rv devholidayge/ holiday/`

Comment: Are you sure it completed with a 0 return code and no errors?
What is the exact command you invoked?

Comment: Does the directory have subdirectories under it? If yes, then `cp` by itself will not do a recursive copy unless you specify the `-R` flag.

Comment: Did you run out of space on the target?

Comment: @MK yes I used -r

Comment: @pjc50 nope. I've many more gigs of space.

Comment: @zmode exact command is in the post. I edited it out.

Comment: Are there subdirectories or files within `devholidayge/` for which you don't have read permission?

Comment: What do the files that didn't copy have in common (if anything)? Were they all over a certain size? Were they all a certain type?

Comment: @ChrisF they were part of the w3 total cache plugin.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze - edit this information into your question.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze Could it be that they were cache files? If so, it is possible that they vanished or were created after the copy started.

Comment: @zmode not possible, they were part of w3-total-cache-config files not cache files.